# ajax jquery refresh the data from the database

Tags: jquery

I have this code,how can I make it ajax jquery? I have a page with articles that are being pull from database and I want that once user click on the button refresh the ajax call will refresh the articles.

```
           <!--  refresh the page with jquery !-->
           <script type="text/javascript">   
                 $(document).ready(function() {      
                 $('#Button_refresh').click(function() {     
                 $.ajax({
}); }); 
           </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Client-side javascript cannot query from database. Well thats not how its done in secure applications at least. You ask from backend (php/asp/python/nodejs..) that should do that.

If you mean just to refresh some div with articles from backend via URL, then just

```
$.get(URL, function(response){
  $('#wrapper').html(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a php file in a folder (if you're using php) and use the php file as control (to retrieve data). First you have to do the ajax "Post" call. Here's some code:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "linktoyourphpfile.php",
            data: { refresh: articles },
            success: function(data)
                    {
              $("#div-id-where-articles-are-generated").html(data);

                    }
           });

            });
```

now after making the call you edit the php file

```
if (isset($_POST['refresh']) {

// you do the query here. It will be an array. So you need a to define a string and  accumulate whatever you need to be written. here's a sample.
 $str=""; //first define the string.

$resultset  //is the array of the results returned by the database. then loop through it.

foreach($resultset as $res)
   {
      $str=$str."<div>$res['somethin']</div>"; //you got the point.

   }
 //then at the end just echo the str.

 echo $str;
}
```